# Incorrect Sytax near ',' in SQL command string (C#)

Tags: c#, sql

I have the following command line written in c#, but I keep getting an exception telling me that there is incorrect syntax near ','. Any ideas?

```
SELECT Name, Age 
FROM testTable 
WHERE Name = 'Roger', Age BETWEEN '19' AND '21', Sex LIKE M%;
```

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Did you also forget quotes around M% or do you use a preprocessor of some kind and why the quotes around the numbers ?

Comment: `Sex LIKE M%` ? What kind of values do you have in that column ?

Comment: 'MALE', 'FEMALE', 'DID NOT SAY', 'TRANSGENDER'

Comment: You would probably use a `=` instead of a `LIKE` when the values are known

Comment: Usually you use an enumerated type and just use = for a sex column, even when you managed to define 10 different sexes

Answer (score 8):

You must use `AND`, not a comma, to separate conditions in `WHERE` :

```
SELECT Name, Age FROM testTable
WHERE Name = 'Roger' AND Age BETWEEN 19 AND 21 AND Sex LIKE 'M%';
```

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong but like use the string so it's correct write 'M%'

Comment: Hahahaha nice one dystroy

Comment: brilliant `AND` amazing

Answer (score 1):

In SQL you must use `AND` or `OR` in the where clause:

In addition, you have 2 other syntax errors:

1. numerics can be literal - use `BETWEEN 19 AND 21` if the columns are numeric
2. The `LIKE` value needs quoting as it is a string `LIKE 'M%'`

The result should be this:

```
SELECT Name, Age FROM testTable WHERE Name = 'Roger' AND Age BETWEEN 19 AND 21 AND Sex LIKE 'M%';
```